# how to select the previous date record from SQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

> i want to select the previous record from the selected date from sql.

**controller**

```
if ($this->input->post("show"))
{
$date=$this->input->post("date");
$where=array("date <="=>$date);
$result=$this->Common_model->select_previous("pso_meter",$where);
var_dump($result);
}
```

**model**

```
public function select_previous($table,$where)
{
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->limit('1');
        $this->db->order_by('date','DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get_where($table, $where);
        return $query->row();
}
```

Comment: have you tried this - `$where=array("date", $date);`

Comment: make sure your `$date` is in `Y-m-d` format

Comment: yes format is Y-m-d

Comment: Ok, did you try the first comment solution?

Comment: yes output is NULL

Comment: Please make sure you have same date format on both sides - array("date <="=>$date). i.e. in the table and $date

Comment: yes the selected date format and date format from the table is same

Comment: yes got its working well now by editing it like $where=array("date <"=>$date);

Comment: @jamilshah but shouldn't it work for `<=` as well?

Comment: @jamilshah I guess, it's alright as long as it works for you. :)

Comment: No it dont work for <= and it return the same selected date record bcoz of = sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Controller**

```
if ($this->input->post("show"))
{
$date=$this->input->post("date");
$where=array("date <"=>$date);
$result=$this->Common_model->select_previous("pso_meter",$where);
var_dump($result);
}
```